# Getting Browser Autocomplete of Ajax Submitted Form Fields Working in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, forms, internet-explorer-8, autocomplete

I have a page that is heavily managed by ajax, and used all day by my clients employees for data entry.

Before a merger the client was using Firefox, but has had to change to IE8 now.

Firefox would save the form inputs when the forms on this page where submitted via ajax, IE8 doesn't do this natively.

Having the forms now not auto-complete has quite an effect on the efficiency the employees are able to use these forms.

**The question:**

Is there anyway I can get IE8 to save form inputs submitted via ajax to be later used for completion?

Without a browser solution I may have to goto a solution like storing the inputs in a database and running a data driven autocomplete...

Comment: I have the samen problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Internet Explorer has an AutoComplete feature that may be of
>   assistance.
>
> You can enable AutoComplete by going to Tools, then Internet Options.
>   On the Internet Options screen go to the Content tab, and click the
>   Settings button in the AutoComplete section. In the Settings check the
>   box next to Forms.

Hope that helps!